# Transform rhombus defined by corners to another rhombus

Tags: graphics, transform

If you have a 2D model in the shape of a rhombus, defined by it's four corners, and you want to transform it into the shape of another rhombus, given it's 4 corners, how would you do this?  Can you do it with a transformation matrix?

My line of thinking is that you can find 4 vectors along the sides such that `||b||/||side_b|| = ||c||/||side_c||, ||a||/||side_a|| = ||b||/||side_b||`, such that `(a,b)` and `(b,c)` cross at `p`.

```
          a
   -------->-------
  |                |
b ^        p       ^ c
  |                |
  |                |
   -------->-------
           b
```

However, I would like the most efficient way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a rhombus can be defined by 2 vectors; scaling on the X axis, and scaling on the y axis. So a matrix that scales a square (we'll say 1x1 dimensions) into a rhombus would look like this: (sorry for the gross matrices! underscores are for spacing)

|X1_1  Y1_1  ___0|

|X1_2  Y1_2  ___0| = Matrix A

|___0  ___0  ___1|

and we want to go from this toward some new dimensions, represented as the following:

|X2_1  Y2_1  ___0|

|X2_2  Y2_2  ___0| = Matrix B

|___0  ___0  ___1|

We want to transform Matrix A into Matrix B. I'll name this transformation T. Therefore:

Matrix A * Transform T = Matrix B.

Doing some basic matrix shuffling, and...

Transform T = Matrix B * inverse(matrix A).

So just fill Matrix B with the dimensions you want, and fill Matrix A with the values you start with.